# Add turf.js script tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, turfjs

I am trying to add turf.js script tag to my asp.net MVC view but the @ symbol in the url is causing the view to fail. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is script tag: `<script src='https://npmcdn.com/@turf/turf/turf.min.js'></script>`

I receive a compilation error because of the /@turf/ section in the URL.

Line 22: https://npmcdn.com/@turf/turf/turf.min.js'>

Answer (score 0):

Add two @ symbols to solve your problem:

```
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@@turf/turf/turf.min.js'></script>
```